# Creating a branch in SVN with files from different folders

Tags: svn, branch

I'm trying to setup the SVN methodology within my company. The thing is, I'd like to create a simple way for our programmers to complete their tasks. We work in task assignments, and a task only modifies a subset of our code base, usually taking objects (files) from various parts of our repository.

What I would like to do is, find a way to create a branch in SVN (imagine its name as the task code from a bug tracker) and inside that branch there's only the files related to that task.

Like this: there's a huge folder structure to separate various modules and parts of the system, but we'll take a small example: folders 1, 2 and 3 with some files inside.
We want to take a file from each folder, and create a branch in /branches/task_1 that contains a file from each folder.

I want to be able to checkout only that branch, with the three files and still have a way to merge the changes back into trunk, without changing the rest of trunk. Is this possible without too much work from our developers?

EDIT: The code is mainly SQL and PL/SQL code, so there's no build to be broken. Please focus on what I'm asking and not in the traditional Software Development paradigm.

EDIT2: Convinced the client to use a traditional SVN strategy! Win!

Comment: If I only pulled a subset of the repository files for a specific task, how would I build the product and verify that my task output compiles and works as expected

Comment: If you are worried about pulling down a whole repo over and over again for each task, look into the switch command that will mitigate that.  (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html)

Comment: @RobGoodwin This is a repo with SQL and PL/SQL code, there's no build except for database compilation of each object. The tasks are organized this way because that's how we deliver things to the client for validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not going to be easy, and rightly so: this is a horrible strategy.

SVN is meant to be used as a series of snapshots of a tree of files. So cherry-picking from the tree into a branch and then trying to merge them back in is going to be tedious, though I don't think it's impossible. Plus you have to look at testing what happens in each task... That's going to have to be tested against the entire application anyhow. So it's kind of pointless to do what you're asking.

Now, if your stuff is modular by design you could store each module in a separate tree or a separate repo and then maintain the full application as a series of `svn:externals`, but that's actually going to make it more complex. I think you're probably going to be better off just doing things the standard way.

> And if you don't think it's impossible, you could at least try to send me in some direction.

Well you will have to create branches from the CLI tool, since I don't know of any client that supports only copying a set of specific files to create a branch (unless that set of files is the contents of a specific dir in the repository). So you or the developer would have to do something like:

`svn cp --parents SVNURL/trunk/file1.sql SVNURL/trunk/file2.sql SVNURL/branches/taskname`

The problem is this is only going to copy the file from trunk, not any intermediate directory structure. So if you have anything but a flat file layout on trunk then you're probably going to get confused when you merge everything back, because whoever is doing the merge will have to just know where to merge everything.

The only way around this I can think of would be to copy each file individually like:

```
svn cp --parents SVNURL/trunk/file1.sql SVNURL/branches/taskname
svn cp --parents SVNURL/trunk/file2.sql SVNURL/branches/taskname
svn cp --parents SVNURL/trunk/migrations/file3.sql SVNURL/branches/taskname/migrations
```

I'm guessing what it boils down to is that when you merge you're going to have to do a cherry-pick merge one file at a time. Which seems like a whole lot of overhead to me for not a lot of benefit.

After your explanation of what you're dealing with here and the workflow, I still think this is a bad idea. You're just going to have a much easier time if you copy TRUNK to BRANCH and then only work on the files necessary. It's pretty easy to see what those files are by just looking at the log.

And if you are worried about your developers accidentally modifying things outside the scope of the task, I'm pretty sure you could just set the permission to only give them commit access to the existing files affected by the task + write permission to add new files if necessary.

Comment: I understand, but this was very very easy to accomplish in CVS, and that's where we're coming from. And if you don't think it's impossible, you could at least try to send me in some direction.

Comment: This is a terrible plan. Please trust me that anyone that spends the time to give you advice on how to carry out your plan isn't really someone you should be taking advice from.  Embrace SVN, don't try to beat it into your old CVS process.  Forget the CVS notion that each file has a revision - in svn the repository has a revision.

Comment: I couldnt agree with @thekbb more.. well except for the my advice part; I warned you. We have all warned you. And when you go down this path and want to shoot yourself in the face, or the rest of the team wants to impale you along the Appian Way, we will not be held responsible.

Comment: sorry didn't mean to lump @prodigitalson in with my comment.  I'd edit it if I could.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Still planning on how to tackle this. Also, this is a client-imposed rule, not the way I'm confortable doing it. Since the SVN is in their hands I kinda have to go with the flow. With this I have at least arguments on how weird their workflow is. Thank you again.

Comment: @prodigitalson We finally implemented SVN with a traditional workflow and things are going well. Just wanted to thank you for your time in answering an apparently crazy question!